# Is using != in a rails view another way to call a helper method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is a straight forward quetion. I have a rails app that uses haml instead of erb and in one of my views at the bottom of the line I see this:

```
!= map_init('map', @account.latitude ? 7 : 0)
```

This `map_init` is for a google maps api rendering and teh `map_init` method is located in a `MapHelper` module. Is this another way of calling a method in a rails view?

I thought it was `-` or `=` to call methods. Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: It means `=` plus HTML unescaping, see the [reference](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#unescaping_html). Probably the `map_init` helper returns some HTML tags that are not marked as `html_safe`.

Comment: Thanks for that link I appreciate it. Cleared things up.

Comment: @BoraMa your comment should have been posted as the answer to this question.

Comment: @smathy, you are right, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means regular `=` (expression call) with HTML unescaping, see the [HAML reference](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#unescaping_html).

So e.g. `!= "<br>"` will become real `<br>` in the final HTML and not `&lt;br&gt;` as would do with plain `=`.

Probably the `map_init` helper returns some HTML tags that are not marked as `html_safe`.